# Covariance and expectation of joint continuous random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, continuity, conditional-expectation, covariance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJEbe.png)

Firstly, for part (a) I have tried calculating this by integrating the conditional pdf along with y in the integral, but just get a messy integral and not sure how you could get a specific number from this. Is this the correct way to do it?
Second, for part (b) again I tried calculating E(x) first but get a horrible integration and not sure how to find the pdf of Y... can anyone help??

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

a)

For a fixed $x\neq0$ function $f_{Y\mid X}\left(y\mid x\right)=x^{2}e^{-yx^{2}}$
can be recognized as PDF of exponential distribution with parameter
$\lambda=x^{2}$.

Consequently $\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid X=x\right]=\frac{1}{\lambda}=x^{-2}$
so that $\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid X\right]=X^{-2}$.

b)

- The PDF of $X$ betrays that there is symmetry wrt to $0$. Based on that it can be shown that for any function $u:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb Eu(X)$ exists and $u(-x)=-u(x)$ for every $x$ we have: $$\mathbb Eu(X)=\mathbb Eu(-X)=-\mathbb Eu(X)\text{ hence }\mathbb Eu(X)=0$$
- $\mathbb{E}XY=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[XY\mid X\right]\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid X\right]\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[XX^{-2}\right]=\mathbb{E}X^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you! As cov(X,Y)=E(X)E(Y)-E(XY)=0-E(XY) does this mean that E(X^-1) also is 0? How can this be shown?

Comment: The covariance equals $\mathbb EXY-\mathbb EX\mathbb EY$ (not $\mathbb EX\mathbb EY-\mathbb EXY$). If $u$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ if $x\neq0$ and $u(0)=0$ then it satisfies $u(-x)=-u(x)$ so yes, if the expectation exists. It remains to be checked that $\mathbb E|X^{-1}|<\infty$

Comment: Oh yes sorry, my mistake. Thank you for your help!